# Binding custom class property of an ASP.NET control from ASCX markup

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

I have an ASCX that inherits from a `WebControl` that has a 'CustomConfiguration' property of type `CollectionConfigurationItem`.  This configuration gets set elsewhere in the code, so by the time it gets to the ASCX it is set up to how I wish to use the data.  At this point I'd like to render out another control using this configuration, like so:

```
<modules:DataModule runat="server" CustomConfiguration="<%# Model.CategoryListConfiguration %>" />
```

However, breaking into `DataModule` always results in 'CustomConfiguration' being null, which is the default value for the property.  I've tried adding a `Bindable` attribute to the property but to no avail, and when I set an EventHandler for the `DataBinding` event on the `DataModule` it doesn't even get called.

How can I set this custom-class-typed property from the markup or, failing that what's the second-best method of getting this to work?  Thanks for any light you can shed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the <%# %> syntax, it doesn't get executed until you databind the control.  Try calling:

```
yourDataModuleID.DataBind();
```

e.g. from your Page_Init method.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple!  Thanks - I'll accept your answer when the system will let me  :)